# dump_coverage.cc:48] Check failed: (java_agent_class) != nullptr

Tags: android, code-coverage, android-12

I am trying to calculate code coverage of instrumented class files on an Android virtual device using `libdumpcoverage.so`. A 64-bit file has been copied to `/system/lib64/` & `jacocoagent.jar` is available under `/system/frameworks/`.

In dump process according to the link, I am getting following error in adb logs

```
dump_coverage.cc:48] Check failed: (java_agent_class) != nullptr
```

I tried to check this with JaCoCo team. they told me check with Android developers.

Comment: How did you instrument your APK?

Answer (score 1):

I set following variables before AOSP build & i got coverage dump after executing steps mentioned in [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/tools/dump-coverage/README.md).

```
 export EMMA_INSTRUMENT_FRAMEWORK=true
 export EMMA_INSTRUMENT=true
 export LOCAL_EMMA_INSTRUMENT=true
```